# Firebase Comments viewing error - Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I try to show comments in the list I got this error -
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToParameterizedType(CustomClassMapper.java:251)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:177)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:593)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)

My comment showing activity -

```
myRef.child("Photo")
            .child(mphoto.getPhoto_id())
            .child("comments")
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: child added.");

                    Query query = myRef
                            .child("Photo")
                            .orderByChild("photo_id")
                            .equalTo(mphoto.getPhoto_id());
                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dsnapshot) {
                            for ( DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dsnapshot.getChildren()){
                                Photo photo = new Photo();
                                Map<String, Object> objectMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) singleSnapshot.getValue();

                                photo.setCaption(objectMap.get("caption").toString());
                                photo.setTags(objectMap.get("tags").toString());
                                photo.setPhoto_id(objectMap.get("photo_id").toString());
                                photo.setUser_id(objectMap.get("user_id").toString());
                                photo.setDate_Created(objectMap.get("date_Created").toString());
                                photo.setImage_Path(objectMap.get("image_Path").toString());

                                mComments.clear();
                                Comments firstComment = new Comments();
                                firstComment.setUser_id(mphoto.getUser_id());
                                firstComment.setComment(mphoto.getCaption());
                                firstComment.setDate_created(mphoto.getDate_Created());
                                mComments.add(firstComment);

                                List<Comments> commentsList = new ArrayList<Comments>();
                                for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : singleSnapshot
                                        .child("comments").getChildren()){
                                    Comments comments = new Comments();
                                    comments.setUser_id(dSnapshot.getValue(Comments.class).getUser_id());
                                    comments.setComment(dSnapshot.getValue(Comments.class).getComment());
                                    comments.setDate_created(dSnapshot.getValue(Comments.class).getDate_created());
                                    mComments.add(comments);
                                }
                                photo.setComments(mComments);
                                mphoto=photo;
                                setupWidgets();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });


                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says

> Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap

This might getting the error

```
Map<String, Object> objectMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) singleSnapshot.getValue();
```

You can change this and make it simple like below

```
String caption = singleSnapshot.child("caption").getValue(String.class);

photo.setCaption(objectMap.get("caption").toString());//So you wont able to do this

photo.setCaption(caption);//And you can use like this
```

Instead of using this

```
Map<String, Object> objectMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) singleSnapshot.getValue();

                            photo.setCaption(objectMap.get("caption").toString());
                            photo.setTags(objectMap.get("tags").toString());
                            photo.setPhoto_id(objectMap.get("photo_id").toString());
                            photo.setUser_id(objectMap.get("user_id").toString());
                            photo.setDate_Created(objectMap.get("date_Created").toString());
                            photo.setImage_Path(objectMap.get("image_Path").toString());
```

Replace it with this

```
 String caption=singleSnapshot.child("caption").getValue(String.class);
 String tags= singleSnapshot.child("tags").getValue(String.class);
 String photo_id=singleSnapshot.child("photo_id").getValue(String.class);
 String user_id= singleSnapshot.child("user_id").getValue(String.class);
 String date_Created = singleSnapshot.child("date_Created").getValue(String.class);
 String image_Path= singleSnapshot.child("image_Path").getValue(String.class);


 photo.setCaption(caption);                      
 photo.setTags(tags);                     
 photo.setPhoto_id(photo_id);                      
 photo.setUser_id(user_id);                      
 photo.setDate_Created(date_Created);       
 photo.setImage_Path(image_Path);
```

As you can see no objectMap

Comment: What error ? u should replace your objectMap

Comment: Error is not their error is in something else.

Comment: But did u tried? if my answer gets the error then you can comment whats the error.

Comment: the error is the same - Expected a List while deserializing but got a class java. util.HashMap